# Number of occurrences of a substring in a string [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, indexing

This peace of code only returns the index of the first match. However I want the array "result" to hold all the indexes of the matches.

```
function score(string,pattern) {
    var v = string.toUpperCase();
    var s = pattern.toUpperCase();
    var result = [];


    result.push(v.indexOf(s)); 
    return result.length;
}
```

Comment: You never seem to accept any answers - it's good practice around here.

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` has a second parameter: `start`.

Try this:

```
function score(string,pattern) {
    var v = string.toUpperCase();
    var s = pattern.toUpperCase();
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var index = v.indexOf(s, i);
        if (index != -1) {
            result.push(index);
            i = index;
        }
    }
```

We are basically iterating over the string, jumping always to the next occurence. Try setting a breakpoint at `result.push(index)`, that might help understanding the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with regular expressions:

EDIT: improved as per Kay's suggestion

```
function score( str, pattern ) {
    pattern = pattern.replace( /([\[\]{}\\*+.?^$\(\)])/g, "\\$1" );

    var re = new RegExp( pattern, "ig" )
      , result = []
      , match
      ;

    while ( match = re.exec( str ) ){
        result.push( match.index );
    }

    return result;
}

score( "0AA34567AA01234AA78900", "AA" ); //[1, 8, 15]
score( "0[[34567[[01234[[78900", "[[" ); //[1, 8, 15]
```

Comment: You should quote "bad" characters in `pattern` before building the regex: `/[\[\]{}\\*+.?^$]/g`.

Comment: Yeah thought of that, but I thought I'd keep it simple. Now that you mention it I'll add it in (you left out round parenthesis btw :)

Comment: Damn, I though a got every special character. :D